# React component event fire manually from client side browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom-events, google-chrome-devtools

In my website, I have created a div element using React Js and it's editable, here if the user edits the content it will trigger the onInput function.

```
r.createElement("div", {
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
                    __html: e
                },
                dir: "auto",
                ref: "input",
                spellCheck: this.props.spellCheck,
                "data-tab": this.props.editable ? 1 : null ,
                contentEditable: this.props.editable,
                className: t,
                onInput: this.onInput,
                onPaste: this.onPaste,
                onCut: this.onCut,
                onKeyUp: this.onKeyUp,
                onKeyPress: this.onKeyPress,
                onMouseDown: this.onMouseDown,
                onContextMenu: this.onContextMenu,
                onFocus: this.props.onFocus,
                onBlur: this.props.onBlur
            }
```

I am trying to set the content to that element from the client chrome browser console and it's not triggering the `onInput` event.

Is there a way to add input **dynamically** and **call `onInput` event** which is attached for the element?

Answer (score 11):

you can dispatch event from console

1.find dom node through querySelector.. , or select element in "Elements" tab and use $0;

```
const input = document.querySelector('[contentEditable]');
```

2.create event

```
const eventX = new Event('input', {bubbles: true});
```

3.change value

```
input.textContent = "TEST";
```

4.dispatch event

```
input.dispatchEvent(eventX)
```

**[jsfiddle DEMO test](http://jsbin.com/fekoxawicu/1/edit?js,console,output)**

[image]

Comment: YOU! ARE GENIUS!! Thank you so much! I thought this was impossible